# Notification animation in CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I am trying to implement some sort of notification animation on the bottom left of the screen in a web page. I want the animation to fade in from left to right in 1s animation, stay there for 5 seconds, fade out to left, and finally deleting the div element of that specific notification. There is an X sign on the top right corner of each notification item by which the user can turn remove it without waiting for it to fade out. I have two problems here, the first problem is in the function responsible for creating a new notification. There is a notification variable inside that function that equals the element of that specific notification. The problem is that the value of that variable changes each time the function is called to create a new instance so that the listeners attached to it are not working and referring the the new item. The second problem is with the animation of fading out the notification when clicking on the X sign. I want it to fade out rather than just disappearing, but adding a class name to the element that has a CSS animation is not working. I do not know why.

HTML

```
<div class='notifications'></div>
```

CSS

```
.notifications {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: 100000000;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.notifications > div {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  animation: goIn 1s ease-out forwards, goOut 1s ease-out forwards 5s;
  box-shadow:  2px 2px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.fading_out {
  opacity: 0 !important;
  transform: translateX(-300px) !important;
  transition: all 1s ease-out !important;
}
.notifications > div.green {
  background-color: #80E76F;
}
.notifications > div.red {
  background-color: #e7816f;
}
.notifications > div.normal {
  background-color: #F2F4FF;
  color: black;
}
@keyframes goIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-300px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
@keyframes goOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-300px);
  }
}
.notifications > div > div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0px 2.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.notifications > div > div:active {
  background-color: #bababa;
}
.notifications > div > div div {
  height: 2.5px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 1.25px;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.notifications > div.normal > div div {
  background-color: black;
}
.notifications > div > div div:first-child {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 7.5px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
notifications_container = document.querySelector('.notifications');
var pushNotification = function (message, color) {
  notification = document.createElement('div');
  x_close = document.createElement('div');
  x_close.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
  x_close.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
  notification.appendChild(x_close);
  notification.appendChild(document.createElement('p').appendChild(document.createTextNode(message)));
  notification.classList.add(color);
  notifications_container.appendChild(notification);
  notification.firstChild.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.parentNode.classList.add('fading_out');
    setTimeout(function () {
      notification.parentNode.removeChild(notification);
    }, 1000);
  });
  setTimeout(function () {
    notification.parentNode.removeChild(notification);
  }, 7000);
}
pushNotification ('I am green', 'green');
pushNotification ('I am red', 'red');
pushNotification ('I am normal', 'normal');
```

Here is a pen to which you can view the animation:
https://codepen.io/ScientificMaster/pen/zYormao

Comment: you can try using a library instead of creating from scratch https://github.com/dgknca/simple-notify

Comment: if you create a pen, for example in codepen, it will be easier for people to help you

Comment: I want to create it with a simple function as the site I am working on does not have sufficient bandwidth for now. I will create a pen and add the link to the question

Comment: Pen added to the question